# How to randomly place images in a tkinter canvas grid

Tags: python, canvas, random, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to create a game where images are placed in random cells of a grid.
I had managed to create a grid and I tried to use that in order to randomly place the images but it does not seem to work as I would like it to.

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk 
    from tkinter.ttk import *
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    from Tkinter import ttk 
    from Tkinter.ttk import *
import random
from random import randint

window = tk.Tk() 
style = ttk.Style(window) 
style.configure("BW.TLabel")
game_frame = tk.Frame(window)
game_grid = tk.Canvas(game_frame, width=450, height=450, borderwidth=0,
                      highlightthickness=0)

def grid_create():
    global row, col, cell_width, cell_height, rect, rows , columns
    rows = 8 
    columns = 8 
    cell_width = 50 
    cell_height = 50 
    rect = {}
    for i in (game_grid, game_frame):
        i.pack()
    for column in range(8):
        for row in range(8):
            x1 = column*cell_width 
            y1 = row * cell_height 
            x2 = x1 + cell_width 
            y2 = y1 + cell_height 
            rect[row,column] = game_grid.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,
                                                       fill="green",
                                                          tags="rect")
    grid_draw()
def grid_draw():
    global row, col
    game_grid.itemconfig("rect", fill="green")
    for i in range(8): 
        row = random.randint(0,8)
        col = random.randint(0,8)
    create_objects()
def create_objects():
    rows = 8 
    columns = 8 
    cell_width = 50 
    cell_height = 50 
    bandits = 5
    bandit_list = {}
    bandit_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="Bandit.png")

    for column in range(randint(0,8)):
        for row in range(randint(0,8)):
            x1 = column*cell_width + 22
            y1 = row * cell_height - 22
            x2 = x1 + cell_width 
            y2 = y1 + cell_height 
            bandit_list[row, column] = game_grid.create_image(x1, y2,
                                                              image=bandit_img)
    for i in range(randint(0,5)):
        row = random.randint(0,8)
        col = random.randint(0,8)
grid_create()
window.mainloop()
```

I only want five 'bandits' to be displayed in random cells - hence the `bandits = 5` - but I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I also do not want any of the 'bandits' to overlap. Any help is appreciated.

**Image:**
[Link to image as I do not have the required reputation to embed it here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtECz.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with `PhotoImage` and `"Garbage Collector"` which remove (from memory) image assigned to local variable in function.

You have to assign it to global variable ie.

```
# create global variable
bandit_img = None

def create_objects():
    # inform function to use global varia
    global bandit_img

    bandit_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="Bandit.png")
```

or to widget instance: see "Note" on page http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

---

To get only 5 bandits you have to get random values `(row,col)` and check if it doesn't exists on bandit list. If `(row,col)` exists on list then you get random values again and again check. You can use `while True` loop and `break` to leave loop when you find unique `(row,col)`

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk 

import random

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

ROWS = 8 
COLUMNS = 8 
CELL_WIDTH = 50 
CELL_HEIGHT = 50
BANDITS_NUMBER = 5

# --- functions ---

def create_grid():

    data = {}

    for col in range(COLUMNS):
        for row in range(ROWS):
            x1 = col * CELL_WIDTH 
            y1 = row * CELL_HEIGHT
            x2 = x1 + CELL_WIDTH 
            y2 = y1 + CELL_HEIGHT
            data[row, col] = game_grid.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2,
                                                       fill="green", tags="rect")

    return data   

def create_bandits(image):

    data = {}

    for i in range(BANDITS_NUMBER):

        while True:
            row = random.randint(0, ROWS-1)
            col = random.randint(0, COLUMNS-1)
            if (row,col) not in data:
                break

        x1 = col * CELL_WIDTH + 22
        y1 = row * CELL_HEIGHT - 22
        x2 = x1 + CELL_WIDTH
        y2 = y1 + CELL_HEIGHT

        data[row, col] = game_grid.create_image(x1, y2, image=image)

    return data

# --- main ---

# - init -

window = tk.Tk() 

game_frame = tk.Frame(window)
game_frame.pack()

game_grid = tk.Canvas(game_frame, width=450, height=450, borderwidth=0,
                      highlightthickness=0)
game_grid.pack()
game_grid.itemconfig("rect", fill="green")

# - data -

rects = create_grid()

# create global variable
bandit_image = tk.PhotoImage(file="Bandit.png")

# send image to function - so you don't need word "global"
bandits = create_bandits(bandit_image)

# - start -

window.mainloop()
```